# presentViewController from TableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, uitableview

I have a TableViewController, TableViewCell and a ViewController. I have a button in the TableViewCell and I want to present ViewController with `presentViewController` (but ViewController doesn't have a view on storyboard). I tried using:

```
@IBAction func playVideo(sender: AnyObject) {
        let vc = ViewController()
        self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

> Error: Value of type TableViewCell has no member presentViewController

---

Then, I tried

`self.window?.rootViewController!.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)`

> Error: Warning: Attempt to present  whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

---

*What am I doing wrong? What should I do in order to presentViewController from TableViewCell? Also how can I pass data to the new presenting VC from TableViewCell?*

---

**Update:**

```
protocol TableViewCellDelegate
{
   buttonDidClicked(result: Int)
}

class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBAction func play(sender: AnyObject) {
        if let id = self.item?["id"].int {
            self.delegate?.buttonDidClicked(id)
        }
    }
}
----------------------------------------

// in TableViewController

var delegate: TableViewCellDelegate?
func buttonDidClicked(result: Int) {
    let vc = ViewController()
    self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

> I receive error: Presenting view controllers on detached view controllers is discouraged

(Please note that I have a chain of NavBar & TabBar behind TableView.)

---

I also tried

```
 self.parentViewController!.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Same Error.

---

Also tried,

```
self.view.window?.rootViewController?.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Same Error

Comment: Is the button meant to be a secondary (e.g., accessory view) selection?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use `protocol` to pass the action back to `tableViewController`

1) Create a `protocol` in your cell class

2) Make the `button` action call your `protocol` func

3) Link your `cell's protocol` in `tableViewController` by `cell.delegate = self`

4) Implement the `cell's protocol` and add your code there

```
let vc = ViewController()
self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: I receive error, Presenting view controllers on detached view controllers is discouraged. And it's crashing afterwords. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @senty could you add your code in the question so I can see your code

Comment: I updated the question and added current code. Can you please check?

Comment: @senty I can't really see any issue from the code structure will cause `Presenting view controllers on detached view controllers is discouraged` but you should check your code and search out about the error

Answer (score 13):

It seems like you've already got the idea that to present a view controller, you need a view controller. So here's what you'll need to do:

1. Create a protocol that will notify the cell's controller that the button was pressed.
2. Create a property in your cell that holds a reference to the delegate that implements your protocol.
3. Call the protocol method on your delegate inside of the button action.
4. Implement the protocol method in your view controller.
5. When configuring your cell, pass the view controller to the cell as the delegate.

Here's some code:

```
// 1.
protocol PlayVideoCellProtocol {
    func playVideoButtonDidSelect()
}

class TableViewCell {
// ...

// 2.
var delegate: PlayVideoCellProtocol!

// 3.
@IBAction func playVideo(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.delegate.playVideoButtonDidSelect()
}

// ...
}


class TableViewController: SuperClass, PlayVideoCellProtocol {

// ...

    // 4.
    func playVideoButtonDidSelect() {
        let viewController = ViewController() // Or however you want to create it.
        self.presentViewController(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        //... Your cell configuration

        // 5.
        cell.delegate = self

        //...
    }
//...
}
```

Comment: Using this approach, I receive : Presenting view controllers on detached view controllers is discouraged. I have no storyboard file for the presenting ViewController()

Comment: I have a hunch that you'll get this error if your TableViewController is being presented modally instead of being pushed onto the navigation stack. Please correct me if I'm misled.

Comment: It's working now, however it doesn't seem good (because I use presentViewController and then dismissViewController when I pull down, but when I'm pulling down the view, behind that view it's all black, and when it dismisses fully, it shows the table view again.) So regarding your comment, it works okay.. I am not sure for other cases beside presentViewController though...

Comment: Right approach!!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and found this code somewhere on stackoverflow, but I can't remember where so it's not my code but i'll present it here.
This is what I use when I want to display a view controller from anywhere, it gives some notice that `keyWindow` is disabled but it works fine.

```
extension UIApplication
{

    class func topViewController(_ base: UIViewController? = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController) -> UIViewController?
    {
        if let nav = base as? UINavigationController
        {
            let top = topViewController(nav.visibleViewController)
            return top
        }

        if let tab = base as? UITabBarController
        {
            if let selected = tab.selectedViewController
            {
                let top = topViewController(selected)
                return top
            }
        }

        if let presented = base?.presentedViewController
        {
            let top = topViewController(presented)
            return top
        }
        return base
    }
}
```

And you can use it anywhere, in my case I used:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)
    let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "WeekViewController")
    UIApplication.topViewController()?.navigationController?.show(vc, sender: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So self.presentViewController is a method from the ViewController.
The reason you are getting this error is because the "self" you are referring is the tableViewCell. And tableViewCell doesn't have method of presentViewController.

I think there are some options you can use:
1.add a delegate and protocol in the cell, when you click on the button, the IBAction will call

```
self.delegate?.didClickButton()
```

Then in your tableVC, you just need to implement this method and call self.presentViewController

2.use a storyboard and a segue
In the storyboard, drag from your button to the VC you want to go.

Comment: This approach doesn't solve my question. Please check my updated question