# UIAlertController in UITableView is returning nil

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller, uitableview

I am using UIAlertController in UITableView. It returns nil value near tableview.delegate = self. Here alertC is the function that presents alert. I am calling that alertC function from tableViewCell when a button is pressed.

```
class AdminPlaces: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
private var placeNames = [String]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.getDataFromFirebase {
        self.tableView.delegate = self
        self.tableView.dataSource = self
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }

   func alertC() {
    let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Delete", message: "Are you sure to delete the place", preferredStyle: .alert)
    let yesAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: .default, handler: nil)

    let noAction = UIAlertAction(title: "No", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
    ac.addAction(yesAction)
    ac.addAction(noAction)
    self.present(ac, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

}


class AdminPlacesCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var placeName: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var delete: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var edit: UIButton!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    edit.alpha = 0
    delete.alpha = 0
}
func configure(place: String) {
    placeName.text = place
}

func showButtons() {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseIn, animations: {
        self.edit.alpha = 1
        self.delete.alpha = 1
    }, completion: nil)

}



@IBAction func onEditClicked(_ sender: Any) {
}
@IBAction func onDeleteClicked(_ sender: Any) {
    let adminPlaces = AdminPlaces()
    adminPlaces.alertC()
}
}
```

I dont understand what is the problem. Why is it returning nil near tableView.delegate= self? What is the correct way todo??

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please check this link as it solved my problem. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34911172/6223683)

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of problems here. 1. alertC exist inside of ViewDidLoad. Move this function out of here. 2. The following code:

```
let adminPlaces = AdminPlaces()
adminPlaces.alertC()
```

says create a brand new instance of AdminPlaces and call alertC() on the new one. This is not the same AdminPlaces that holds the tableView will the cell. The new one is has not been presented and thus will not show the alert. 3. Your alert exists on the ViewController and your cell doesn't have a direct way of accessing it.

Use the UITableViewDelegate method tableView:commit:editingStyle. When the user deletes the cell from editing mode this method is called. Call your alertC() method from here.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But it was just that I did not write alertC() function in viewDidLoad. It was just a mistake in my copy paste. Any how thank you.

Comment: I got the answer from this link. Any one who has the same problem can refer to this. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34911172/6223683)